How do I create a table and a bar chart inside a single TikZ node?
\begin{center}
\begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth, center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2.5cm, xshift=-2cm]
% Node style
\tikzstyle{node} = [draw, rectangle, minimum width=15cm, text centered, inner sep=10pt]

% Root node (węzeł 0)
\node (root) [node, text width=15cm, align=center, inner sep=10pt] {
    \textbf{\fontsize{45}{36}\selectfont{Węzeł 0}} \\ 
    % Tabela
    \scalebox{2.9}{
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}  % Zwiększenie wysokości wierszy
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}  % Obramowanie wokół tabeli
        \hline
        \textbf{Kategoria} & \textbf{\%} & \textbf{n} \\ \hline
        niskie & 59,9 & 1033 \\ \hline
        umiarkowane & 16,8 & 290 \\ \hline
        wysokie & 23,3 & 402 \\ \hline
        \textbf{Ogółem} & \textbf{100,0} & \textbf{1725} \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    }

    % Adding space between table and columns
    \\[1cm]
    % Posts
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[fill=green!70] (0,0) rectangle (5.99,1); % Zielony - długość 59.9%
        \draw[fill=blue!70] (6.1,0) rectangle (7.78,0.6); % Niebieski - długość 16.8%
        \draw[fill=red!70] (7.9,0) rectangle (10.22,0.8); % Czerwony - długość 23.3%
    \end{tikzpicture}
};

% Child nodes
\node (node1) [node, below left=2cm and 2cm of root, text width=14cm, align=center, inner sep=10pt] { % Zwiększenie odległości
    \textbf{\fontsize{45}{36}\selectfont{Węzeł 1}}  \\ [0.5cm]
    \scalebox{3}{
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \begin{tabular}{c c c}
        \hline
        \textbf{Kategoria} & \textbf{\%} & \textbf{n} \\ \hline
        niskie & 88,1 & 620 \\ \hline
        umiarkowane & 3,8 & 27 \\ \hline
        wysokie & 8,1 & 57 \\ \hline
        \textbf{Ogółem} & \textbf{40,8} & \textbf{704} \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    }
};

\node (node2) [node, below right=2cm and 2cm of root, text width=15cm, align=center, inner sep=10pt] { % Zwiększenie odległości
    \textbf{\fontsize{45}{36}\selectfont{Węzeł 2}}  \\
    \scalebox{3}{ 
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \textbf{Kategoria} & \textbf{\%} & \textbf{n} \\ \hline
        niskie & 40,5 & 413 \\ \hline
        umiarkowane & 25,8 & 263 \\ \hline
        wysokie & 33,8 & 345 \\ \hline
        \textbf{Ogółem} & \textbf{59,2} & \textbf{1021} \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    }
};
\draw [arrow] (root.south) -- ++(0,-1) -- ++(-3,0) -- (node1.north);
\draw [arrow] (root.south) -- ++(0,-1) -- ++(3,0) -- (node2.north);

% Sub-nodes of node1
\node (node3) [node, below left=2cm and 2cm of node1,  text width=14cm, align=center, inner sep=10pt] { % Zwiększenie odległości
    \textbf{\fontsize{45}{36}\selectfont{Węzeł 3}} \\
    \scalebox{3}{ 
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \textbf{Kategoria} & \textbf{\%} & \textbf{n} \\ \hline
        niskie & 86,9 & 479 \\ \hline
        umiarkowane & 4,0 & 22 \\ \hline
        wysokie & 9,1 & 50 \\ \hline
        \textbf{Ogółem} & \textbf{31,9} & \textbf{551} \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    }
};

\node (node4) [node, below right=2cm and 2cm of node3, text width=14cm, align=center, inner sep=10pt] { % Zwiększenie odległości
    \textbf{\fontsize{45}{36}\selectfont{Węzeł 4}}  \\
    \scalebox{3}{ 
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5} 
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \textbf{Kategoria} & \textbf{\%} & \textbf{n} \\ \hline
        niskie & 92,2 & 141 \\ \hline
        umiarkowane & 3,3 & 5 \\ \hline
        wysokie & 4,6 & 7 \\ \hline
        \textbf{Ogółem} & \textbf{8,9} & \textbf{153} \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    }
};
% Połączenia dla HIPOTEKA
\draw [arrow] (node1.south) -- ++(0,-1) -- ++(-3,0) -- (node3.north);
\draw [arrow] (node1.south) -- ++(0,-1) -- ++(3,0) -- (node4.north);

% Sub-nodes of node2
\node (node5) [node, below left=3cm and 2cm of node2,  text width=14cm, align=center, inner sep=10pt] { % Zwiększenie odległości
    \textbf{\fontsize{45}{36}\selectfont{Węzeł 5}} \\
    \scalebox{3}{
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}  
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \textbf{Kategoria} & \textbf{\%} & \textbf{n} \\ \hline
        niskie & 49,8 & 238 \\ \hline
        umiarkowane & 28,2 & 135 \\ \hline
        wysokie & 22,0 & 105 \\ \hline
        \textbf{Ogółem} & \textbf{27,7} & \textbf{478} \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    }
};

\node (node6) [node, below right=3cm and 0.1cm of node2,  text width=14cm, align=center, inner sep=10pt] { % Zwiększenie odległości
    \textbf{\fontsize{45}{36}\selectfont{Węzeł 6}} \\
    \scalebox{3}{
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5} 
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \textbf{Kategoria} & \textbf{\%} & \textbf{n} \\ \hline
        niskie & 32,2 & 175 \\ \hline
        umiarkowane & 23,6 & 128 \\ \hline
        wysokie & 44,2 & 240 \\ \hline
        \textbf{Ogółem} & \textbf{31,5} & \textbf{543} \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    }
};
% Połączenia dla WIEK
\draw [arrow] (node2.south) -- ++(0,-1) -- ++(-3,0) -- (node5.north);
\draw [arrow] (node2.south) -- ++(0,-1) -- ++(3,0) -- (node6.north);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{center}


Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Please note that \tikzstyle is deprecated. Have a look at \tikzset instead.

You should never nest tikzpictures

Scaling elements which contain text, like tables, is usually a bad idea.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Welcome to TeX.SX!

Sorry, it's a pain to get even some lines up and running ... much is caused by missing preamble. E.g. even this one doesn't where I tried to revitalize your code step by step (see below).
Because you didn't add a screenshot or so it's hard to guess, what you want as a final result. I assume, you want something like this, where I used Tikz to arrange a few images, only with different objects:

If so, I suggest to compile tables and barcharts separately using class standalone AND include their pdf s in your main document via package graphicx. Here are two examples for this approach:

Semiconductors value chart
PI controller

Your gain in flexibility can't be overrated.

"Warning ... painful compiles ahead" (unfortunately)
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}

\begin{document}

%\begin{center}
%\begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth, center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2.5cm, xshift=-2cm]
% Styl węzłów
\tikzstyle{node} = [draw, rectangle, minimum width=15cm, text centered, inner sep=10pt]

% Root node (węzeł 0)
\node (root) [node, text width=15cm, align=center, inner sep=10pt] {
%    \textbf{\fontsize{45}{36}\selectfont{Węzeł 0}} \\ 
    \textbf{\fontsize{45}{36}}} \\ % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    % Tabela
%    \scalebox{2.9}{
%    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}  % Zwiększenie wysokości wierszy
%    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}  % Obramowanie wokół tabeli
%        \hline
%        \textbf{Kategoria} & \textbf{\%} & \textbf{n} \\ \hline
%        niskie & 59,9 & 1033 \\ \hline
%        umiarkowane & 16,8 & 290 \\ \hline
%        wysokie & 23,3 & 402 \\ \hline
%        \textbf{Ogółem} & \textbf{100,0} & \textbf{1725} \\ \hline
%    \end{tabular}
%    }
%
%    % Dodanie przestrzeni między tabelą a słupkami
%    \\[1cm]  % Przestrzeń pomiędzy tabelą a słupkami
%    % Słupki
%    \begin{tikzpicture}
%        \draw[fill=green!70] (0,0) rectangle (5.99,1); % Zielony - długość 59.9%
%        \draw[fill=blue!70] (6.1,0) rectangle (7.78,0.6); % Niebieski - długość 16.8%
%        \draw[fill=red!70] (7.9,0) rectangle (10.22,0.8); % Czerwony - długość 23.3%
%    \end{tikzpicture}
};
%
%
%
%% Child nodes
%\node (node1) [node, below left=2cm and 2cm of root, text width=14cm, align=center, inner sep=10pt] { % Zwiększenie odległości
%    \textbf{\fontsize{45}{36}\selectfont{Węzeł 1}}  \\ [0.5cm]
%    \scalebox{3}{
%    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
%    \begin{tabular}{c c c}
%        \hline
%        \textbf{Kategoria} & \textbf{\%} & \textbf{n} \\ \hline
%        niskie & 88,1 & 620 \\ \hline
%        umiarkowane & 3,8 & 27 \\ \hline
%        wysokie & 8,1 & 57 \\ \hline
%        \textbf{Ogółem} & \textbf{40,8} & \textbf{704} \\ \hline
%    \end{tabular}
%    }
%};
%
%
%\node (node2) [node, below right=2cm and 2cm of root, text width=15cm, align=center, inner sep=10pt] { % Zwiększenie odległości
%    \textbf{\fontsize{45}{36}\selectfont{Węzeł 2}}  \\
%    \scalebox{3}{ 
%    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
%    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
%        \hline
%        \textbf{Kategoria} & \textbf{\%} & \textbf{n} \\ \hline
%        niskie & 40,5 & 413 \\ \hline
%        umiarkowane & 25,8 & 263 \\ \hline
%        wysokie & 33,8 & 345 \\ \hline
%        \textbf{Ogółem} & \textbf{59,2} & \textbf{1021} \\ \hline
%    \end{tabular}
%    }
%};
%\draw [arrow] (root.south) -- ++(0,-1) -- ++(-3,0) -- (node1.north);
%\draw [arrow] (root.south) -- ++(0,-1) -- ++(3,0) -- (node2.north);
%
%% Sub-nodes of node1
%\node (node3) [node, below left=2cm and 2cm of node1,  text width=14cm, align=center, inner sep=10pt] { % Zwiększenie odległości
%    \textbf{\fontsize{45}{36}\selectfont{Węzeł 3}} \\
%    \scalebox{3}{ 
%    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
%    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
%        \hline
%        \textbf{Kategoria} & \textbf{\%} & \textbf{n} \\ \hline
%        niskie & 86,9 & 479 \\ \hline
%        umiarkowane & 4,0 & 22 \\ \hline
%        wysokie & 9,1 & 50 \\ \hline
%        \textbf{Ogółem} & \textbf{31,9} & \textbf{551} \\ \hline
%    \end{tabular}
%    }
%};
%
%
%
%\node (node4) [node, below right=2cm and 2cm of node3, text width=14cm, align=center, inner sep=10pt] { % Zwiększenie odległości
%    \textbf{\fontsize{45}{36}\selectfont{Węzeł 4}}  \\
%    \scalebox{3}{ 
%    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5} 
%    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
%        \hline
%        \textbf{Kategoria} & \textbf{\%} & \textbf{n} \\ \hline
%        niskie & 92,2 & 141 \\ \hline
%        umiarkowane & 3,3 & 5 \\ \hline
%        wysokie & 4,6 & 7 \\ \hline
%        \textbf{Ogółem} & \textbf{8,9} & \textbf{153} \\ \hline
%    \end{tabular}
%    }
%};
%% Połączenia dla HIPOTEKA
%\draw [arrow] (node1.south) -- ++(0,-1) -- ++(-3,0) -- (node3.north);
%\draw [arrow] (node1.south) -- ++(0,-1) -- ++(3,0) -- (node4.north);
%% Sub-nodes of node2
%\node (node5) [node, below left=3cm and 2cm of node2,  text width=14cm, align=center, inner sep=10pt] { % Zwiększenie odległości
%    \textbf{\fontsize{45}{36}\selectfont{Węzeł 5}} \\
%    \scalebox{3}{
%    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}  
%    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
%        \hline
%        \textbf{Kategoria} & \textbf{\%} & \textbf{n} \\ \hline
%        niskie & 49,8 & 238 \\ \hline
%        umiarkowane & 28,2 & 135 \\ \hline
%        wysokie & 22,0 & 105 \\ \hline
%        \textbf{Ogółem} & \textbf{27,7} & \textbf{478} \\ \hline
%    \end{tabular}
%    }
%};
%
%
%\node (node6) [node, below right=3cm and 0.1cm of node2,  text width=14cm, align=center, inner sep=10pt] { % Zwiększenie odległości
%    \textbf{\fontsize{45}{36}\selectfont{Węzeł 6}} \\
%    \scalebox{3}{
%    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5} 
%    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
%        \hline
%        \textbf{Kategoria} & \textbf{\%} & \textbf{n} \\ \hline
%        niskie & 32,2 & 175 \\ \hline
%        umiarkowane & 23,6 & 128 \\ \hline
%        wysokie & 44,2 & 240 \\ \hline
%        \textbf{Ogółem} & \textbf{31,5} & \textbf{543} \\ \hline
%    \end{tabular}
%    }
%};
%% Połączenia dla WIEK
%\draw [arrow] (node2.south) -- ++(0,-1) -- ++(-3,0) -- (node5.north);
%\draw [arrow] (node2.south) -- ++(0,-1) -- ++(3,0) -- (node6.north);


\end{tikzpicture}
%\end{adjustbox}
%\end{center}


\end{document}

